# how to create a pipe which reacts to language change

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-pipe

I have an item with optional "description" and "descriptionEn" attributes. There is a logic which controls how to display the item based on the selected language (we use ngx translate) and the presence and value of "description" and "descriptionEn" attibutes.

It became unpractical to implement the logic in the template so I moved it into a custom pipe.

The pipe's value is the item, and the first argument is the selected language.

In the template I use the pipe like this:

```
<div>{{item | xpipe:_translate.currentLang}}</div>
```

_translate is injected in the component's constructor:

```
constructor(public _translate: TranslateService) {}
```

The pipe's code:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'xpipe'
})
export class XpipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    if(args.length != 1) {
      console.debug("incorrect number of args")
      return "";
    }
    // do the complicated logic which depends on selected language and item
    if(args[0]==="en") {
      if(value.descriptionEn) {
        return "something when lang is EN and item has endesc";
      }
      else {
        return "something when lang is EN and item has NO endesc";
      }
    }
    else {
      if(value.description) {
        return "something when lang is NOT EN and item has desc";
      }
      else {
        return "something when lang is NOT EN and item has NO desc";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to avoid the argument for the pipe? I mean that the selected language is a global state of the app, so it seems superfluous to pass it everytime I use the pipe.

I can get the language state in the pipe via TranslateService but I don't know how to trigger recalculation of the pipe when the lang is changed and how to unsubscribe TranslateService (no ngOnDestroy on PipeTransform).

So if it's possible, how should I do that?

Comment: `ngx-translate` has a `translate` pipe that seems to be doing what you have tried in your code. Have you taken a look at  it? https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive

Comment: @Mike: afaik translate pipe is only able to select a translation for a key according to the selected language. What I need is to calculate a string (not simply selecting from a map) based on an object's properties AND on selected language. But if translate pipe can be used for this, please point to that!

Comment: @Mike: nevertheless it seems that it is possible to write a pipe which reacts to something other than changes on it's input and arguments; translate of ngx-translate is an example. I need something similar, but I am stuck particularly with triggering pipe recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

I currently save my language state in a service and call that service from my pipe:

**Translation Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'translation',
})
export class TranslationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translationService: TranslationService) {}

  transform(value: string, language?: string, replace?: string): string {
    if (replace) {
      return this.translationService
        .translate(value, language)
        .replace('%%', replace);
    }
    return this.translationService.translate(value, language);
  }
}
```

**Translation Service**

```
export type TranslationSet = {
  values: { [key: string]: string };
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TranslationService {
  public values: { [key: string]: string } = {};

  public languages = ['ptBr', 'es', 'enUs'];

  public language = 'ptBr';

  private dictionary: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } } = {
    ptBr: {
      new: 'Novo',
      delete: 'Excluir',
      helloName: 'Oi %%',
    },
    es: {
      new: 'Nuevo',
      delete: 'Deletar',
      helloName: 'Hola %%',
    },
    enUs: {
      new: 'New',
      delete: 'Delete',
      helloName: 'Hello %%',
    },
  };
  constructor() {}

  translate(key: string, language = this.language, replace?: string): string {
    if (replace) {
      return this.dictionary[language][key].replace('%%', replace);
    }
    return this.dictionary[language][key];
  }
}
```